# How to set @media for html email?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have set some @media when user click email from gmail or chrome desktop ?

But I have no idea why chrome desktop will get @media for mobile style css.

I hope `html email` from desktop can use `@media screen and (min-width: 1024px)` not my default style.

What I did wrong ?

Here is my @media setting

```
/* without @media is for my mobile device */
```

for mini tablet

```
min-width: 540px
```

for tablet

```
min-width: 768px
```

for desktop

```
min-width: 1024px


<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  main {
    height: 100%;
  }
    
  /* for mobile : real mobile device open from Gmail APP layout will have default margin left and right */
                
  .user-name {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0 0 0px 0;
  }
  .unread-message {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .unread-type {
    font-size: 10px;
   }
                
  /* for mini tablet */
  @media screen and (min-width: 540px) {
    .user-name {
      font-size: 20px;
      margin: 0 0 14px 0;
    }
    .unread-message {
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    .unread-type {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  }
    
  /* for tablet */
  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .user-name {
      font-size: 20px;
      margin: 0 0 14px 0;
    }
    .unread-message {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    .unread-type {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  }
    
  /* for desktop */
  @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .user-name {
      font-size: 20px;
      margin: 0 0 14px 0;
    }
    .unread-message {
      font-size: 14px;
     }
    .unread-type {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical breakpoints for email are:

<450 for mobile
450-600 for tablet
600+ for desktop

I.e. change `@media screen and (min-width: 1024px)` to `@media screen and (min-width: 600px)` and Google Chrome and other desktop apps/webmail will use these.

Comment: What's your source for stating these are "typical"?

Comment: Myself :) having worked in email development exclusively for the last five years. But you could go through really good emails (google it) if you like - they have examples in the wild with code.